Ideal Cipher assumption for DES collision probability: Dan Boneh Coursera lecture
In Dan Boneh's lecture Exhaustive Search Attacks from module 2 of his coursera course, he gives an explanation for why the probability of two different DES keys mapping the same plaintext to the same cipher text is $\frac{1}{2^{8}}=\frac{1}{256}$ if we assume DES is an ideal cipher.

It wasn't clear to me how he was using the ideal cipher assumption (he has not defined it at this point in the course) nor which entities were random variables. I attempted my own analysis independently but came up with a different answer. What am I missing?
I assume the joint distribution over $K1$ and $K2$ is uniform over the $[2^{56}]^2$ possible pairs of keys except it is 0 over the $2^{56}$ locations where $K1=K2$. This means $P(K1=a, K2=b) = 1/([2^{56}]^2 - 2^{56})$ where $a\neq b$ and $0$ otherwise.
Because E(k, m) is an ideal cipher, it acts like a random oracle for fixed k and fixed m with a uniform distribution on the set of possible permutations on 64 bit strings. That is, it seems E itself is a random variable even when its inputs are not random variables.
For a given plaintext m, the probability that two keys map it to the same ciphertext is
$$\sum_{k1} \sum_{k2} P\left(E(k1, m) = E(k2, m) | k1, k2\right) P(k1, k2)$$
(ideal cipher assumption: collision probability for a pair is 1 / number of alternatives)
$$\sum_{k1} \sum_{k2} \frac{1}{2^{64}} P(k1, k2)$$
$$\sum_{k1} \sum_{k2} \frac{1}{2^{64}} \frac{1}{(2^{56})^2 - 2^{56}}$$
$$\left((2^{56})^2 - 2^{56}\right) \frac{1}{2^{64}} \frac{1}{(2^{56})^2 - 2^{56}}$$
$$\frac{1}{2^{64}}$$
But this can't be right because it would always result in the same answer regardless of how big the key space is. (perhaps it makes sense that the probability would always be the same because we are asking the probability of two keys randomly sampled having a match, and they don't behave differently even if there are more of them).

I think that in Boneh's analysis, $k$ (what you call $K_1$) is fixed.
We are given an input-output sample of the block cipher $c = E(k,m)$, which we assume was already computed using a particular, fixed (but unknown) key $k$.
Then we ask, what is the probability that some different $k' \ne k$ also satisfies $c = E(k',m)$?

If you fix an arbitrary $k' \ne k$, then the event $E(k,m) = E(k',m)$ happens with probability $1/2^{64}$.
Why?
In this expression, $E(k,m)$ and $k'$ are already fixed, so the probability is over the value of $E(k',m)$ alone.
It is thanks to the ideal cipher model that we can assign a probability distribution to $E(k',m)$.
Since $k' \ne k$, the permutation $E(k',\cdot)$ is completely independent of the values that have been previously fixed, so $E(k',m)$ is uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}^{64}$.

Sum this probability $1/2^{64}$ over all $2^{56}-1$ possible choices of $k' \ne k$ and you have the given bound.


